# C# WEB API How to HttpPost with Parameter and how to httpsGet string and return custom List

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, in-memory-database

I am doing a WEB API which generates a random Credit Card Number with the clients email.

First, how can I can, without Postman JSON code, Post the clients email and the credit card number and de ID just by https://localhost:44355/api/ClienteDados/"Typing the email here". This below is what I have so far. I manage to do it with Postman, but I want to do it in the URL.

My Class is ClienteDados.

Int ID

string EmailId

string NumCartao

My context is _context.

My DB is ApiContext and DbSet ClientesDB

```
[HttpPost("{email}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ClienteDados>> PostClienteDados(string email, ClienteDados clienteDados)
    {
        //Begin
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int cardNumber1 = rnd.Next(4572, 4999);
        int cardNumber2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        int cardNumber3 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        int cardNumber4 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        clienteDados.NumCartao = $"{cardNumber1} {cardNumber2} {cardNumber3} {cardNumber4}";
        clienteDados.EmailId = email;
        //End

        
        _context.ClientesDB.Add(clienteDados);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        return CreatedAtAction("GetClienteDados", new { id = clienteDados.NumCartao }, clienteDados.NumCartao);
    }
```

After I registred the clientes info with EF Inmemory, I want to make a HttpGet of all credit cards from the parameter EMAIL. So when they type /email/"email here" it show a LIST of all credit card numbers in that email.

How can I do the list, and how can I do the search by the string Email? all the time I can only search by int ID.

```
[HttpGet, Route("email/{email}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ClienteDados>>> GetEmail(string email)
    {


        var cc = await _context.ClientesDB.FindAsync(email);

        return Ok(cc);

    }
```

The Https Get above does not work yet because it's a string, it only works with the int ID.
Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT 1
So I managed to get the List by the url parameter, but its showing me the id, the email and the CC Number, how can I filter it just to CC number?

```
List<ClienteDados> list = await _context.ClientesDB.Where(a => a.EmailId.Equals(email)).ToListAsync();
       return Ok(list);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to put the CC number as a url parameter?

Comment: I want to put email as parameter. Both in Post and Get @JeffB

Comment: You are going to want to be _very_ careful with credit card numbers (read up on PCI DSS). In fact, if you can figure out how to handle credit cards without ever handling the CC number or other card info, you'll be much happier

Comment: @Flydog57 Is correct. You can be opening yourself up to some serious legal action. It is best to use a provider. But to answer your url param question, I will post info on that for you.

Comment: Thats not for commercial use, it's just for self learning @Flydog57  basicaly I wanto to know how can i make a custom list from a parameter, and how to post and info from a url parameter

Comment: @JeffB would you be able to help me on this?

Comment: @user66756 I have put in an answer, if you have questions, reply to that.

Comment: This should be two separate questions. There are two questions in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
List<ClienteDados> list = await _context.ClientesDB.Where(a => a.EmailId.Equals(email)).ToListAsync();
   return Ok(list);
```

to:

```
var list = _context.ClientesDB.Where(a => a.EmailId.Equals(email)).Select(s => new { NumCartao  = s.NumCartao }).ToList();
   return Ok(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code in your `GetEmail` function

```
await _context.ClientesDB.Where(a => a.EmailId.Equals(email)).ToListAsync();
```

UPDATE:

First you can create a new TYPE

```
    class NEW_TYPE
    {
        public string CARD_ { get; set; }
    };
```

then inside the function use this query

```
                var query = from a in _context.ClientesDB
                    where a.EmailId.Equals(email)
                    select new NEW_TYPE
                    {
                        CARD_ = a.NumCartao
                    };

                var cc = await query.ToListAsync();
                return cc;
```

`cc` will be a list of `NEW_TYPE` which contain only card info `List<NEW_TYPE>`

Comment: Its partially working. I am getting all info back, I want just the credit card number. how can I filter it to receiver all credit card numbers with that email, only, I dont want to see the ID neither the EmailId. The list is returning everything @wowoot

Comment: You can change the return type to `Task<List<NEW_TYPE>>` then return `cc` the `cc` contains `List<NEW_TYPE>` only cards

Comment: If it worked for you , then this is the important thing, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. The other part of the problem, would you be able to help me? I need to HttpPost the info by URL parameter, not by JSON codes. So /email/"..." they insert the email and create the date, straight in the browser @WowoOt

Comment: I did not understand the problem !

Comment: So now, If I want to input the clients info, I need to use JSON in Postman. however, I want to use the URL parameter https://localhost:44355/api/ClienteDados/"email" to create the email, so when i type my email in the url, it creates from it, whitout postman, makes sense now?  [HttpPost("{email}")] @wowoot

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using URL parameters in POST especially when working with emails , because the `@` sign will give you some problems in URLs . You can use `Form` data to pass your data from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference [THIS](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api) website for additional information.

Using this example:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Test(int age)
{
    Console.Write(age);
}
```

You can create a request like so:
[image]

C# will consume the url parameters and bring them into the call. Please note, the variable names MUST match the parameter variables for it to work. Notice how I used `int age` and `age` in both places. You need to put url params first.

In your case, you would pass the email, like so:

```
https://localhost:5443/controller/test?email=email@email.com
```

And the function in c# would have string email as the first item in the function input variables. `public void Test(string email)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will definetely read the link you shared with me and try it again.
on the other hand, 
List<ClienteDados> list = await _context.ClientesDB.Where(a => a.EmailId.Equals(email)).ToListAsync();
           return Ok(list);

How can I return this list but with a parameter, I want to return only the credit card number, not all the info. The list i correct, I just need to filter it. How can I do it? @JeffB

Comment: @user66756 It looks like you are using EF? Do: .MyTable.Where(u => u.EmailId == email).Select(u => u.CreditCardNumber)

Comment: I fixed already. But the code you gave me says it doesnt contains definition for "GetAwaiter". but this part I fixed already, thanks